# How can I preserve volumes in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose down and my question is how can I save my volumes when I execute this command?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `docker-compose down` should not remove any volume unless you add `--volumes` (or `-v`) flag (see the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)). However, you can set volumes as external, which will always prevent them from deletion:

```yaml
volumes:
  myapp:
    external: true
```

You can find this example in official [docker volumes documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose).

Answer (score 0):

The `docker-compose down` command stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up.

By default, the only things removed are:

- Containers for services defined in the Compose file
- Networks defined in the networks section of the Compose file
- The default network, if one is used

Networks and volumes defined as external are never removed.

A volume may be created directly outside of compose with docker volume create and then referenced inside `docker-compose.yml` as follows:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  frontend:
    image: node:lts
    volumes:
      - myapp:/home/node/app
volumes:
  myapp:
    external: true
```

Comment: It's weird but it removes my volumes.

Comment: Please give an appropriate citation to the Docker documentation if you're quoting it directly.